# modulus.io SSL need key file?

Tags: ssl, openssl, hosting, web-hosting

I would like to get SSL running on my subdomain api.rofulus.com

I checked out https://modulus.io/codex/projects/ssl

I created a certificate and key with:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myserver.key -out server.csrls
```

I registered me on namecheap an bought a positiveSSL

https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/domain-validation.aspx

I uploaded the content of the server file to namecheap and I received 3 files:

api_rofulus_com.crt
PositiveSSLCA2.crt
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt

But for custom SSL I need content of a key file. But my myserver.key is empty. So where or how can I get the key?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is `server.csrls` a typo? It shouldn't have an 'ls': `server.csr`.

Answer (score 0):

By using this command you have created certificate request server.csr:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myserver.key -out server.csr
```

To see the contents of the request you can use:

```
openssl req -noout -text -in server.csr
```

Then you have uploaded server.csr to namecheap and got your certificates.

If your private key (myserver.key) is empty then i think you somehow corrupted it. You can reissue you certificate with the new key and certificate request. Drop a line to namecheap support, i think they can resolve this situation.